# Insert data from a tsv file from web in postgres table

Tags: postgresql, csv, insert

This question has been has asked but I am unable to find proper solution to that. I would like to COPY data from the columns present in a tsv file available at a web link and insert it into an already created table under a schema.

I have used the query below but I am unable to get any output.

```
COPY schema.table FROM PROGRAM 'curl "ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/intact/current/various/mutations.tsv"'

COPY schema.table FROM PROGRAM 'wget -q -O - "$@" "ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/intact/current/various/mutations.tsv HEADER TSV DELIMITER '\t'
```

Any suggestions here would be really helpful.

Comment: "unable to get any output."  What output were you expecting to get?  Is it just because you didn't end the line with a ';'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I consider a bad practice to download files into the database server - not to mention executing external software to do so. In other words, don't let your database server have access to the internet unless it's really necessary.

That being said, I'd recommend you to download this file of yours in your client and upload it using `psql`. It will work no matter where you download the file and you won't have to deal with possible security breaches or read/write permissions in the server.

Downloading and importing a TSV file in two steps:

```
$ wget -O mutations.tsv "ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/intact/current/various/mutations.tsv"
$ cat mutations.tsv | psql -d your_db -c "COPY your_table FROM STDIN DELIMITER E'\t'"
```

Comment: Interesting. Why is it worse to use `curl` on the server than on the client? If you don't trust `root`, you are lost anyway.

Comment: I'm just not very comfortable letting my server access the internet to download a file. Imho, database systems should be used just for storage and not be able to do such a thing

Answer (score 0):

You should use the CSV format and the tab character as a separator:

```
COPY atable
FROM PROGRAM 'curl "ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/intact/current/various/mutations.tsv"'
   (FORMAT 'csv', HEADER, DELIMITER E'\t');
```

Comment: Above query runs for sometime and then exit with this error: `[Code: 0, SQL State: 38000]  ERROR: program "curl "ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/intact/current/various/mutations.tsv"" failed
  Detail: child process exited with exit code 7`

Comment: According to the documentation of `curl`, that is "Failed to connect to host." Different problem.